# Call a callback function in VC++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, callback

I need to call a callback function in VC++ dll from C# application. Following is the call back function in VC++.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK My_Proc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    . . . . .   
}
```

I have imported the dll , but I do not know how to call the function from C#.  Any thoughts?

```
public class testClass
{
    internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
    {
        const string _dllLocation = "test.dll";

        [DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int My_Proc(int value1, int value2, Int64 value3, int value4);// am getting stuck here

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem??? Also `Int64` seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The correct declaration is:

```
    [DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr My_Proc(IntPtr hDlg, int message, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
```

This is the declaration for a dialog procedure of a native dialog.  Windows is supposed to call it, not you.  It does so when a new Windows message is available for the dialog.  It very rarely gets exported from a DLL, that would explain having problems too.  Getting the correct window handle (hDlg) isn't easy either. But you didn't document your problem well so I can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

in the VC++ all you should use the dll handle:

```
hInst = ::GetModuleHandle("test.dll");
DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, My_Proc);
```